# I am writing a simple php code to check if number is odd or even

Tags: php

I am trying to write a SIMPLE php code to see if number is odd or even but i keep getting an error saying "expected statment" after the closing bracket on the if statement. can someone please explain what i need to do?

```
<?php


function odd_or_even($num) {

    if ($num % 2 == 0);
    {
        print'Number is even';


    } else {

        print 'odd';
    }


}
```

Comment: `if ($num % 2 == 0);` <<< that "ends" the statement. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php - Remove the `;`.

Comment: You shouldn't have a semi-colon at the end of that line - that terminates the expression

Comment: I see a semi colon that will upset most compilers; giving the "hey I was expecting something" error

Comment: In the future you should include that error message.

Comment: @chris85 Actually, there wouldn't be an error, since the semi-colon (end of statement) is actually "valid", *believe it or not* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The `else` is unexpected because the conditional becomes a one liner that does nothing. The `expected statment` the OP mentions is a mis-quoted error message. (answer and your original comment still correct, just OP should include the message so we know what he/she is getting)

Comment: @chris85 Ah yes, you're right and I've added your comment to the wiki answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Posting as a community wiki.

As I stated in comments:

```
if ($num % 2 == 0);
                  ^ ends/terminates the statement.
```

As per what the manual states on line termination:

> *As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated with a semicolon** at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.*

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Answer: **Remove it.**

---

Taken from comments:

*"The `else` is unexpected because the conditional becomes a one liner that does nothing. The expected statment the OP mentions is a mis-quoted error message. – chris85"*

---

What you posted should have thrown you the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

But you failed to post that actual error message.

Comment: @silvesterpinari The question should be marked as solved then.